# Add a local jar file to dependencies of a project in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have two java projects. The first one builds a jar archive with `so` libraries:

```
jar {
    from('libs') {
        include '**/*.so'
        into('native-libs')
    }
}
```

`so` files are included in the first jar.

The second one depends on the first and should include all files from the first. I write:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':project-native')
}
```

but in the second jar I don't see files from the first project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A project dependency adds the dependent JAR file to the classpath of that project. It does not merge the classes into its JAR file.

Comment: and how do force merge?

Comment: You will have to write a task of type `Jar` or modify the existing default jar task as you did above. Why do you want to do that?